# How to adjust encoding to read accent marks properly in R

Tags: r, expss, r-labelled

I am using read_labelled_csv from expss package to read a labelled csv in R.

```
data1<-expss::read_labelled_csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Data/Example.csv")
```

I have a problem reading the labels that has accents. The label looks like this: cafË³ and it has to look this way: café.

How can I adjust the encoding to read properly the accents or how can I write it and which encoding should I use?

Comment: Try to add ```fileEncoding = "UTF-8"```

Comment: When I try it, I got this error: `Error in gsub("\"\"", "\"", df[[i]], fixed = TRUE) : 
  input string 1044 is invalid UTF-8`

Comment: I tried with the write_labelled_csv function also and I get the same error message

Comment: Could you provide example of your data?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. try to add encoding="UTF-8"

```
data1<-expss::read_labelled_csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Data/Example.csv", encoding="UTF-8")
```

Another solution is to use the old functions

```
old_write_labelled_csv (data1,filename = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Data/Example.csv")

data1<- old_read_labelled_csv ("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Data/Example.csv",encoding="UTF-8")
```